# Skylander Battle Mode

Tags: skylanders-giants

I just bought my son the a Wii console and the Skylander Giants starter pack.  The Wii came with a nunchuck but the skylander starter pack did not.  When we chose battle mode the Wii said both players need nunchucks.  Can he play battle mode with just one  player?

Answer (score 3):

**No**

The *Battle Mode* is the multiplayer head-to-head mode of *Skylander Giants*. This mean you play **against** an other (human) player.

However, **you could play the in the *Story Mode* alone**, **or** with the help of an other (human) player.